# Reset all view helpers in Zend Framework

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, view-helpers

Is there a way to reset the state of all view helpers, for example remove all scripts added with `headScript()`? Scripts and meta tags added in one unit test are being seen by the following unit tests even though I am creating a new controller and view for each test. This is causing false positives and negatives.

Comment: Why not just use the setup/teardown methods of phpunit (i assume youre isng phpunit with ZF)?

Comment: You can clean the Zend_Registry in your teardown method using  Zend_Registry::_unsetInstance();

Comment: @prodigitalson - Yes, we're using PHPUnit, but the problem is that I don't know what to put into `tearDown()` to clear the view helpers.

Comment: @Marcin - We have a class that sweeps any new objects out of the Zend Registry already, but that led to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marcin's comment led me to the root cause of the problem in our testing framework, which is that the placeholder registry was being added to the Zend registry before the code that takes a snapshot of the registry was run. Thus, when the code that removes all new registry objects run, it was no longer removing the placeholder registry.

To reset the state for all placeholder-based view helpers, use this:

```
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
unset($registry['Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry']);
```

Comment: This will blow out _all_ placeholders.  A little shoot first, questions later, IMO.

Comment: @JasonTFeatheringham - That's precisely the point. Each unit test should run in complete isolation without being affected by tests run before it.

Answer (score 4):

Having a look at the the abstract class for those containers (`Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Container_Abstract`), I see it extends [ArrayObject](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php). Any time you `set` it replaces that Array's values with an array that wraps the value you set. When you `append`, it gets the old values and unshifts the new value onto the array. So, in theory, you'd be able to use the [exchangeArray](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.exchangearray.php) method to clear any values by passing a blank array (completely untested):

```
$this->view->headScript()->exchangeArray(array());
```

Comment: Doing this for every placeholder-based view helper would have been a last resort, but thanks for the pointer. That would certainly do the trick.